# Возможные варианты аутентификации запроса

Tags: http

Есть js скрипт который подключаеться к разным сайтам и делает запросы к моему API.

Какие это домены будут мне известно, и нужно на бекенде разрешить принимать запросы только от них.

Я нашел решение - проверять Origin заголовок запроса. Вопрос - насколько надежное это решение ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain 
самый надежное это решение  вот вам ссылка можете ознокомиться с етим